# Uso dell'aggettivo "concavo"

Tags: word-usage, etymology, mathematics

Non so se questa sia la sede adatta per porre questa domanda. Tuttavia, dato che in questa comunità vi è molta gente che ha dimestichezza sia con la lingua italiana che con la matematica, credo possa essere base di una discussione interessante.

Come è noto, in italiano l'aggettivo [concavo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/concavo/) viene usato normalmente per descrivere oggetti "a forma di U". Il guscio di una noce aperta, una ciotola su un tavolo, una mano a cucchiaio, sono tutti oggetti che potremmo descrivere come concavi. Ciò avviene generalmente perché si guardano dall'alto verso il basso.

Se ne trova testimonianza anche in letteratura. Ad esempio, nella traduzione italiana di Rosa Calzecchi Onesti del primo libro dell'Iliade, nei versi in cui si parla della ritirata di Achille dalla guerra, si legge

> Ma ora andrò a Ftia, perché certo è molto
>   meglio / andarsene in patria sopra le **concave**
>   navi.

La nave, in effetti, è un altro oggetto che durante la navigazione personalmente classificherei decisamente come concavo.

Tutto ciò è in contrasto con la definizione convenzionale di *[funzione concava](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funzione_concava)* che si dà in analisi matematica.

> [...] una funzione f(x) a valori reali definita su un intervallo si dice concava se il segmento che congiunge due qualsiasi punti del suo grafico si trova al di sotto del grafico stesso.

Per quanto la definizione sulla pagina di Wikipedia italiano non sia rigorosissima, è chiaro che - se mi passate i termini - una funzione concava non è "a forma di nave" bensì "a forma di collina".

Personalmente sono sempre stato turbato da questo contrasto, e volevo sapere se qualcuno aveva informazioni sull'origine di questa discrepanza.

**NB**

So bene che una funzione concava dista una trasformazione lineare dal diventare convessa. Non è quello il punto. La domanda è più incentrata sulla discrepanza tra l'uso che si fa dei termini nella lingua parlata ed in ambiti matematicamente formali.

Comment: Giusto, domanda interessante. La cosa è ancora più curiosa perché ne segue che la regione di piano compresa fra il grafico di una funzione concava, l'asse delle x e le rette verticali corrispondenti agli estremi del dominio della funzione – che ha spesso interesse quando si considera una funzione sui reali – è convessa, e viceversa per una funzione convessa.

Comment: Onestamente, visto che i termini 'concavo' e 'convesso' per le funzioni e per i sottoinsiemi sono gli stessi in più o meno tutte le lingue che parlo, mi sembra più una domanda per [hsm.se]

Comment: @DenisNardis sì, forse è il caso. Domani la porrò lì dopo averla tradotta.

Comment: È un accidente storico. L'interno di un cerchio è un insieme convesso perché contiene tutto il segmento che congiunge due punti qualsiasi della circonferenza; lo stesso vale per la parabola (l'interno è formato dai punti per i quali non passano tangenti alla curva). Perché si sia passati a considerare il “sopragrafico”, non lo so, ma direi perché le curve studiate per prime erano del tipo y=x^n.

Comment: Perdonami, premesso che il discorso su “concavo” detto delle navi etc. è impeccabile, che traduzione dell'Iliade citi? Sembra quella di Rosa Calzecchi Onesti. Chi la attribuisce a “Francesco Monti”?

Comment: @DaG hai ragione, stavo confrontando versioni e mi sono sbagliato, correggo subito.

Comment: Vedo che alla fine non hai posto la domanda su hsm.SE.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Da quello che ricordo dai miei anni di "liceo" (cioè, più o meno come la preistoria), non sono sicura che questo sia stato sempre così per le funzioni.

Comment: @Charo vero, anche perché sono abbastanza soddisfatto della risposta di egreg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'ambiguità c'è già in latino. Il “Lewis and Short” dà come traduzione di *convexus*

> [vaulted, arched, rounded, convex, concave.](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dconvexus1)

Per *concavus* dà

> [hollow, concave; arched, vaulted; bent, curved](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dconcavus)

Credo che l'uso del termine *convesso* in matematica sia, come in molti altri casi, solo un accidente storico e va preso così com'è senza pensarci troppo.

Un insieme di punti del piano è convesso se ogni segmento congiungente due punti della frontiera è contenuto nell'insieme stesso. Per definire una funzione convessa, si guarda se il “sopragrafico” è convesso. Perché? Perché così qualcuno ha cominciato.

Comment: Infatti, quando ero nei due ultimi anni di quello che nel mio paese era più o meno equivalente al liceo, ricordo di aver avuto un anno una definizione di funzioni concave e convesse e l'anno seguente la definizione contraria, fatto che per me fu davvero sorprendente.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: lascio la risposta, ma i commenti mi hanno convinto che non ho colto appieno il problema. Ripensandoci ora, c'è un problema ancora diverso alla base, ed è che "concavo" e "convesso" si usano sia per oggetti di codimensione 0 (come una noce o una collina, pensata come oggetto solido e non come "tratto di penna su un foglio") che di codimensione 1 (come un guscio di noce, o un cucchiaio, o un tratto di penna su un foglio). Mentre nel primo caso il significato dei due termini si può definire più o meno universalmente (perlomeno "convesso"), nel secondo dipende da dove sta l'osservatore.

---

La contraddizione sparisce se "guardi il grafico" dall'asse delle x anziché dall'alto. Difatti l'oggetto che si considera di solito in matematica è il sopragrafico ${(x,y) \in Dom(f) \times \mathbb{R} \colon y \geq f(x)}$, non il sottografico che cita @Dag nel suo commento.

L'equivalenza è: funzione convessa $\iff$ sopragrafico convesso $\iff$ sopragrafico a forma di collina.

In entrambi gli usi di "concavo", in realtà, c'è un certo grado di ambiguità perché se un oggetto è concavo o meno dipende da dove sta l'osservatore: una nave vista dal porto è convessa, non concava.

In alternativa, potresti pensare di far puntare l'asse $y$ verso il basso, cosa che in realtà non è poi così tanto insolita (pensa a come si mettono gli indici in una matrice, per esempio, o le coordinate sullo schermo di un computer).

Comment: In che senso “di solito”? Parlando di integrali, che non sono un aspetto secondario della matematica, si considera quello che chiami “sottografico”, per esempio.

Comment: @DaG Non precisamente; si considera la parte di piano delimitata dalla curva e dall'asse delle ascisse, che può essere sotto (funzione positiva) o sopra (funzione negativa).

Comment: Non mi trovo con l'equivalenza. Un sopragrafico convesso ha la forma di una "collina al rovescio". Inoltre: è vero che l'ambiguità c'è, ma una nave vista dal porto, se consideriamo il mare come piano azimutale, a mio avviso è concava. L'analogia in analisi potrebbe essere f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2. A forma di "barca sul mare" se consideriamo il piano costruito con gli assi x e y, concava per i comuni mortali, convessa in analisi (in quanto somma di funzioni convesse).

Comment: @egreg Giusto. Rimane il fatto che sarei curioso di conoscere eventuali altri usi “soliti” del “sopragrafico” oltre a quello invocato qui.

Comment: @DaG Si usa nelle questioni di convessità e concavità. La scelta è del tutto arbitraria: funzione convessa significa “sopragrafico convesso” per convenzione.

Comment: @DaG C'è qualche altro uso (ad esempio Wikipedia cita un criterio di semicontinuità inferiore), ma  l'analisi convessa è un argomento sufficientemente grosso e importante che anche se fosse usato solo lì non mi sembra un problema.

Comment: @egreg. Grazie, è proprio quello di cui stiamo parlando. Cercavo un chiarimento sul “di solito” (quindi, a quanto pare, al di fuori di queste funzioni) usato da Federico.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Certo, nessun problema. È solo che se per spiegare la terminologia dell'analisi convessa ci rifacciamo alla terminologia dell'analisi convessa non siamo arrivati molto lontano. Poi mi va benissimo la spiegazione di egreg: sia la matematica che le lingue naturali sono piene di cose che sono andate in un modo così come potevano andare in un altro.

Comment: +1 per l'edit e il pensiero sulle codimensioni.